# armadillo c++ comparison

Tags: c++, armadillo

```
  arma::vec::fixed<3> a({1.0, 2.0, 3.0});
  double b = arma::norm(a, 2);
  double c = arma::norm(a, 2);

  // show 0, why?
  std::cerr << (arma::norm(a, 2) == arma::norm(a, 2)) << std::endl;
  // show 1, ok
  std::cerr << (b == c) << std::endl;
```

I'm confused. Why is this happening?

Comment: never never never compare floating point values for euqality using op==. Read http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/02/22/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/ or the goldberg paper to understand why.

Comment: computer is strictly deterministic machine. on the same input data should produce the same output data. second statement demonstrates this

Comment: Just that your first statement and second statement are not the same. and the determinism you talk about happens on a so much lower level that a lot of it is lost at the high language level you are able to perceive.

Comment: @herolover - I can't repeat your results. In both cases I get the output of 1, when using gcc and various optimization settings. Are you sure you don't have a bug somewhere else in your code?